# Checking if a class has a function (return type and const checked)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

Given

```
class A {
public:
    bool foo(int) const {return true;}
};
```

I want `HasFooWithStringReturnTypeAndIsConst<A>::value` and
`HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsNotConst<A>::value` to be false (`HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsConst<A>::value` already returns true so that is working fine).  Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    bool foo(int) const {return true;}
};

template <typename...> struct voider {using type = void;};

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <typename T, typename = void_t<T>>
struct HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsNotConst : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsNotConst<T,
        void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo(std::declval<int>()))>> {
    using Foo = bool (T::*)(int);
    template <typename U> static std::true_type test (Foo*);
    template <typename U> static std::false_type test (...);
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
};

template <typename T, typename = void_t<T>>
struct HasFooWithStringReturnTypeAndIsConst : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasFooWithStringReturnTypeAndIsConst<T,
        void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().foo(std::declval<int>()))>> {
    using Foo = std::string (T::*)(int) const;
    template <typename U> static std::true_type test (Foo*);
    template <typename U> static std::false_type test (...);
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<decltype(test<T>(nullptr)), std::true_type>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << HasFooWithStringReturnTypeAndIsConst<A>::value << '\n';  // true (should be false!)
    std::cout << HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsNotConst<A>::value << '\n';  // true (should be false!)
}
```

Can someone explain why they are returning `true` instead of `false`?  How to fix them so that they return false?  `A::foo(int)` is a const function that returns bool, so they are supposed to return false, aren't they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check is for:

```
decltype(test<T>(nullptr))
```

And the two overloads are:

```
template <typename U> static std::true_type test(Foo*);
template <typename U> static std::false_type test(...);
```

Nowhere in here are you actually considering `&T::foo`. You are just checking if you can convert `nullptr` to some arbitrary pointer type. Which, of course you can. That's why it ends up as `true_type`. What you want to check is if you can convert `&T::foo` specifically to that type:

```
template <typename U> static std::true_type test (std::string (U::*)(int) const );
template <typename U> static std::false_type test (...);
static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(&T::foo))::value;
```

Note that you can do this all much simpler in the partial specialization directly via:

```
template <typename T>
struct HasFooWithStringReturnTypeAndIsConst<T,
            std::enable_if_t<
                std::is_same<std::string,
                             decltype(std::declval<const T&>().foo(0))
                             >::value
            >> : std::true_type { };
```

Here, we're checking if `foo()` is `const` by calling it on a `const T&`, and then simply checking that its return type is `std::string`.

Comment: @ Barry   There is a problem with your second solution.  Both the `const T&` and `T&` versions will return true when the `T&` version should not.  Here's a demo:  http://ideone.com/P6hD7D

Comment: @prestokeys There's no problem with the solution. I never claimed it would check that it's NOT const.

Comment: How to modify your second solution so that will check non-constness?  Your first solution does the job though.

Comment: @prestokeys Have the specialization of `HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsNotConst` inherit from `!HasFooWithBoolReturnTypeAndIsConst` instead of `true_type`.

Comment: @  Barry   Ok, I think your latest idea works.  I tested it with `A` and with a new class `B` that has `foo` which is not const.  I hope this is what you meant:  http://ideone.com/UqrjOv   The output is correct at least.